# Searching for a specific website designer

Tags: web-development

I am searching for a website designer that enables end-users to upload text, pictures, and videos. The problem: The software and file package behind the finished site has to be available for download.

Why? I want to archive the webpage with the uploaded information after a couple of months locally.

Any recommendation?

Comment: What OS should it run on (or what technology – eg. PHP or Python – shall it use if it should be a web-based solution)? What is your price limit when it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking :-( "The software and file package behind the finished site has to be available for download ... I want to archive the webpage with the uploaded information ... locally". So, you just want to make a copy on your local PC (complete with uploaded user data)? Just download it with FTP - but be aware that you will also have to export any databases used

Comment: And don't forget that it the solution uses an database, you will have to download that too.

Comment: Did you Google for "site ripper"?

Comment: I asked this question over a year ago. Since then I learned how to build serverless websites in AWS, with cupholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortenately from your question, i cannot get out at all what you are looking for.

I interpret you need a recommendation for frontend+backend solution for uploading files.

High level answer: you can use dropbox.com to let your users upload the stuff to your account.

Low level anser: try dhtmx.com stuff, it provides backend and frontend componends. Look out for dhtmlx vault component and their backend php examples

Comment: I ended up using Dropbox.